# Kahler differential

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm learning about this theory and trying to make example but i don't uderstand what could the module of differential $A[X,Y]/(XY)$ over $A$ for example (for $A$ a commutative ring).
Thanks if someone could help me !

Comment: I'm pretty sure you just differentiate the polynomial defining the algebra.  Since $d(XY) = Y \, dX + X \, dY$, then $\Omega_{S/A} = (S \, dX \oplus S \, dY)/(Y \, dX + X \, dY)$, where $S = A[X,Y]/(XY)$.

Comment: Yeah it make sense i think